# Updating records codeigniter by using url helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, updates

I am trying to update a table where id of the row is entered and title is selected through a dropdown list, but I have two problems. Firstly Im not sure how to pass the data to the model, and the second problem is actually updating the table using active record.

controller class

```
function edit_profile($id) 
        {   
            $data = array(
                'table_name' => 'user',
                'id' => $id ,
                'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname')
            );

            if($this->user_model->upddata($data))
            {
                $data['msg']= 'Update Done';
                $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
                $this->load->view("edit_profile_view.php", $data);
                $this->load->view('sidbar_user_view',$data);
                $this->load->view('footer_view',$data); 
            }
            else
            {
                $data['msg']= 'Update Not Done';
                $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
                $this->load->view("edit_profile_view.php", $data);
                $this->load->view('sidbar_user_view',$data);
                $this->load->view('footer_view',$data); 

            }

        }
```

model class

```
        function upddata($data) {
        extract($data);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($table_name, array('fullname' => $fullname));
        return true;
}
```

view

```
<?php echo form_open("profile/edit_profile/$d->id"); ?>
            <div class="tuple">
                <h1>full name : </h1>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" class="t-name" readonly value="<?=fullname; ?>" >
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Save" id="mysubmit">
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and when open url

/site/profile/edit_profile/1

i get this message

Fatal error: Call to a member function upddata() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your model in controller like

```
function edit_profile($id) {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    //Do other things
}
```

And it is **optional** like

```
function uppdata($data) {

    $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
    $this->db->update($data['table_name'], array('fullname' => $data['fullname']));
    return true;
}
```

From `$data` also you can directly get the relavent values.ANd you need to pass `$data` to the view file not the `$data1` because it is un-defined and

Replace

```
 $this->load->view("edit_profile_view.php", $data);
```

to

```
 $this->load->view("edit_profile_view", $data);
```

Comment: i will edit my code but i got this message 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant fullname - assumed 'fullname'

Filename: views/edit_profile_view.php

Line Number: 7

Comment: Where is your $data1 defined..??

Comment: I think it would be $data

Comment: Now what it results..??

Comment: on view i canot read this <h1><?=fullname; ?></h1> how can i put fullname from data base to <input type="text" name="fullname" class="t-name" value="<?=fullname; ?>" >